# Implementing Localytics SDK prevents unit tests from building

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios7, localytics

I have recently implemented [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com) to get a better understanding of how our users are using our app.

The [integration guide](http://www.localytics.com/docs/sdks-integration-guides/ios/) is pretty straight forward. However the unit tests can't be built any longer, when I run them.

[image]

The error is familiar to me. This error usually happens if the tested class is not part of the test target membership.

[image]

But the SDK `_OBJC_CLASS_$_LocalyticsSession` provides only a .h file. In order to make it part of the target membership, I needed the .m file, which I don't have.

Has anyone else utilised Localystics and can advice me how to proceed this regarding? Thanks

**UPDATE**

coneybeare's answer has actually made me try this:

[image]

The test target is set to None. But if I change it to target the app itself:

[image]

Then it works. However everytime I intend to run the unit tests the whole app has to start in the simulator, which is very irritating (and slow). Am I missing something? How else can I associate the `.a` code libraries with the test targets?

Comment: Glad to see you got this straightened out! Feel free to email us at support@localytics.com if you have any other SDK questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Localytics, but inspecing the SDK downloads shows a few `.a` code libraries. Ensure those are associated with the test targets.

Comment: Check the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, under the target's Build Phases tab. Ensure the a file is there on the test target.